# How can I access ExtJS elements using `document.querySelector()`?

Tags: javascript, extjs, domdocument, extjs3, dropzone.js

I'm attempting to integrate the http://www.dropzonejs.com/ file uploader into an existing ExtJS 3.4 application. I'm running into problems, as the elements created by ExtJS do not seem to be available using native `document.` methods, used by DropzoneJS.

I want to render the upload panel inside a dynamically created ExtJS window:

```
App.DropzoneWindow = function(config) {
    config = config || {};
    Ext.applyIf(config, {
        url: App.config.connectorUrl
        ,dropzone: null
        ,base_params: {}
    });
    OB.DropzoneWindow.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    this.dropzone = this.initDropzoneJs();
};
Ext.extend(App.DropzoneWindow, App.Window, {
    initDropzoneJs: function() {
        var config = {
            url: this.url
        };
        return new Dropzone('div#'+this.id, config);
    }
});
Ext.reg('app-dropzone-window', App.DropzoneWindow);
```

Dropzone.js is throwing an error "Invalid dropzone element" immediately, as it's trying to access my target window element using `document.querySelector()`. Here are the lines in throwing the error in the source code:

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/master/downloads/dropzone.js#L636-L640

Any ideas how I can achieve this without modifying the Dropzone.js source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to access elements before panel is rendered, so that will never give you elements

use afterrender event to initialize DropZone.js

```
App.DropzoneWindow = function(config) {
    config = config || {};
    Ext.applyIf(config, {
        renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
        listeners : {
             afterrender : this.initDropzoneJs,
             scope : this
        }
    });

    OB.DropzoneWindow.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
};
Ext.extend(App.DropzoneWindow, App.Window, {
    initDropzoneJs: function() {
        var config = {
            url: this.url
        };
        return new Dropzone('div#'+this.id, config);
    }
});
Ext.reg('app-dropzone-window', App.DropzoneWindow);
```

Comment: Facepalm moment! Thanks for the suggestion; works perfectly :)